# How to update web.config now inner showing inner pages

Tags: php, wordpress, windows, permalinks, iis-10

i'm using windows server and wordpress site not showing inner pages, It show only home page and wordpress admin page. While click save changes in "Permalink Settings" it show "You should update your web.config now."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGQlb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHtov.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress: http://test.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

how can fix that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress

Comment: same problem

and show me

500 – Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Could you please tell me the details error message about the 500 error?